# Changing summary from outside preferenceactivity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I am using a preferenceActivity in android to manipulate my shared preferences. I figured out how to change the summary with an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener from within the preferenceActivity. However, I am using a picker wheel so I use an intent to launch it from the preference activity like this...

```
<Preference
        android:summary="Snooze Picker Wheel"
        android:title="Snooze Timer" 
        android:key="snooze_pref">

        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.example.alarm.SnoozePicker"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.alarm" />
    </Preference>
```

I've been researching, but I cannot find a way to update the summary of the picker wheel to the item that is selected. 
So my question is, is there a way to change the summary of a preferenceActivity from a different activity? What would be the implementation for that, and where could I learn more about specifically changing the summary from a different activity? Thank you for any help.

**Edit:** I got something working by setting a shared preference in the snoozePicker activity and then setting it like this in the preference activity in onCreate and onResume

```
if (sharedpreferences.contains(Snooze)) {
        int prefs = sharedpreferences.getInt(Snooze, -1);
        Preference editSnoozePref = (Preference) findPreference("snooze_pref");
        editSnoozePref
        .setSummary("Snooze Setting is " + prefs + " minutes");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to change summary from other `Activity`.
 As a work around, you can save the summary in a `SharedPreference` and set this summary when your `PreferenceActivity` is created. It will be seamless experience for the user as the summary will be visible only after `PreferenceActivity` is created.

Comment: Okay, so I would create the value in a shared preference from a different activity and then update the summary when the PreferenceActivity is created or resumed?

Comment: Are you still there @jungleboy ? I have another quick question

Comment: Yes, tell me. I am here only

Comment: I've tried to change the value of the summary for my snooze picker, but its not letting me. I tried to create an android:key="snooze_key" to the xml code above so that I could use that to find the EditTextPreference but it didn't work. so how can I access the summary of the xml code that i posted?

Comment: You should only set the summary text in `SharedPreferences`. You won't be able to access summary in other `Activity`.